# Load CalDav on Elementary OS 6

Tags: pantheon-mail, switchboard

I am trying to load my Google CalDav on Elementary OS 6.1 however I keep getting a 401 error when trying to load it using online accounts.

Any idea if its broken or if I am doing it wrong. I do have 2FA setup and I also have an app password set that I am using

Would appreciate some insight here